# Why does aggregating a field which contains a conversion function cause a conversion error?

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have an odd issue.

**Context:**
I'm writing a report in SSRS's Report Builder 3.0. I am forced by circumstance to use a pre-defined data model, *I have no direct query access to the database* and therefore cannot directly use `CAST` in SQL or anything like that. I have to stick to the functions in Report Builder's Query Designer.

**Problem:**
I have a table of data with a row per student per subject per "result type", and a column of associated results which are nvarchar format, some of which values are a combination of letters and some are a combination of numbers, for example:

```
| Student Number | Subject | Result Type | Result |
|----------------|---------|-------------|--------|
|  0123456       | Maths   |   ELRCC     |  XEA   |
|  0123456       | Maths   |   ELMSS     |  110   |
```

Having already filtered out the non-'numeric' rows, I need to convert the remaining 'numeric' Results to a numeric datatype, which I am doing via the `INT()` function in Report Builder's query designer. This works fine.

I am then grouping the data in Query Designer on Student Number and wrapping the `INT()` with `AVERAGE()` to get `AVERAGE(INT(Result))` - when I try and run the query with that formula included as a field however the report server throws the following error:

```
===================================

An error occurred while executing the query.
An error occurred when the query ran. Refer to the inner exception for details. (Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder)

===================================

An error occurred when the query ran. Refer to the inner exception for details. (mscorlib)

------------------------------
Program Location:


Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.RsClient.RsCommand.ExecuteRsDataReader()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.RsClient.RsCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.RsClient.RsCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.ReportServerDataProvider.RSDPCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.QueryDesigners.MultiThreadedQueryResultsHelper.AsyncExecuteReader(IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behaviour)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed, MessageData& msgData)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.QueryDesigners.MultiThreadedQueryResultsHelper.ExecuteReaderHandler.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.QueryDesigners.MultiThreadedQueryResultsHelper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ExecuteActiveQueryCallback>b__0()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.QueryDesigners.QueryResultsGrid.EndExecuteReaderInUiThread(GetDataReaderHandler getDataReaderCallback)

===================================

The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
<detail><ErrorCode xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">rsSemanticQueryEngineError</ErrorCode><HttpStatus xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">400</HttpStatus><Message xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">Semantic query execution failed. Error converting data type nvarchar to float.</Message><HelpLink xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&amp;EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&amp;EvtID=rsSemanticQueryEngineError&amp;ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&amp;ProdVer=11.0.5058.0</HelpLink><ProductName xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services</ProductName><ProductVersion xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">11.0.5058.0</ProductVersion><ProductLocaleId xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">127</ProductLocaleId><OperatingSystem xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">OsIndependent</OperatingSystem><CountryLocaleId xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">1033</CountryLocaleId><MoreInformation xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices"><Source>Microsoft.ReportingServices.SemanticQueryEngine</Source><Message msrs:ErrorCode="rsSemanticQueryEngineError" msrs:HelpLink="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&amp;EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&amp;EvtID=rsSemanticQueryEngineError&amp;ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&amp;ProdVer=11.0.5058.0" xmlns:msrs="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">Semantic query execution failed. Error converting data type nvarchar to float.</Message></MoreInformation><Warnings xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices" /></detail>

===================================

The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. (System)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.RsClient.RsCommand.ExecuteRsDataReader()
```

The most relevant line of that being:

`Semantic query execution failed. Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.`

I don't understand why I get that error. The `INT()` function has already performed that conversion, and it does so perfectly fine; I can run the query with just `INT(Result)` and it returns the data fine. So why, given that the conversion step apparently works fine, is SSRS throwing an error when I try to perform aggregation on that converted field?

Comment: Try `CDbl()` instead of integer. Maybe your number is to large for an integer. Or you mistyped average because the function for average is `Avg()`.

Comment: @Strawberryshrub thanks - I'm actually inside the Query Designer using the New Field functionality, so the syntax is a little different (I.E. it really is `INT()` and `AVERAGE()` rather than `CInt()` and `Avg()`. Yay microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

I test this in my environment, it will work well(=Avg(int(Fields!result.Value))). And I think this might not be the expression problem. This might be server or tool problem. 
In addition, you also could refer to [this fix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2456499/fix-error-message-when-you-try-to-execute-a-semantic-query-that-is-bas)
 for details.

Zoe